# Replace back button with side menu icon in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have created an Ionic app with side menu. There is one page 'test.html' on which I can come in 2 ways i.e. from side menu as well as on button click. Button is on page 'test2.html'.

When I'm coming from side menu to test.html, its working fine. But when I'm coming to  on button click, Back button is showing instead of side menu icon.

I always want to show side menu here.

Please see below image:

[image]

**SideMenu.html**

```
 <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false" class="menu-page">
      <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
     </ion-nav-back-button>
     <ion-nav-buttons side="left" >
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
   </ion-nav-bar>
   <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
 </ion-side-menu-content>
 <ion-side-menu side="left" class="left-nav">

   <ion-content scroll="false"  has-bouncing="false">
    <div class="user-info text-center">

   </div>
     <ion-list>
          <a class="item item-icon-left" menu-close ui-sref="app.menuscreen" ui-sref-active="selected">
             <i class="ion-home"></i><span>Home</span>
         </a>
      </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: use `this.navCtrl.setRoot(MYPAGE)` instead of `this.navCtrl.push(MYPAGE)`

Comment: Where i need to add this? I'm working on ionic1

Comment: Sorry i thought you were using ionic 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of ui-sref use ng-click function and

```
$scope.function($scope, $state, $ionicHistory)
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
   disableBack: true
});
$state.go("your page path");
})
```